# Is there any way to make pnpm resolve peer dependencies against sibilings?

Tags: pnpm

I have created a pretty flexible NPM build system for my personal projects. Everything is broken up into individual packages which can then be composed in a consuming project as-needed. This allows different projects to experiment with different configurations, while still re-using a common setup where appropriate. This is a good approach for side projects where one of the key goals is experimentation.

Two of my packages are a jest configuration and the eslint configuration for jest. They would be added as siblings to one of my applications, like this:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@me/eslint-config-jest": "1.0.0",
        "@me/jest-config": "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

In thise case, `jest-config` will provide Jest 29.6.1, and `eslint-config-jest` has a peerDependency of Jest ^29.6.0. With yarn, everything worked great.

I'm beginning to explore pnpm and I've already discovered how it resolves peer dependencies differently. Apparently it ignores siblings and only looks at the parent. This means that `eslint-config-jest` has a missing peer dependency because my application is pulling in Jest from `jest-config` and has not added it directly. The dependencies between the siblings are fully compatible, but pnpm cannot see them correctly.

I'm wondering what the recommended approach to resolving this issue is. Obviously I can use ignoreMissing in my pnpm package.json settings, like this:

```
{
    "pnpm": {
        "peerDependencyRules": {
            "ignoreMissing": ["jest"]
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't like making my resolutions lenient like that. Anyway, I'm just wondering what the recommended solution here would be.